# Como enviar los datos de un ListView con PopupMenuButton a otro ListView de otra vista

Tags: listview, flutter, popup

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en la cual al seleccionar el `ListView` puedo enviar los datos mediante el siguiente método

```
onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HimnoDetalle(todo: Himnoslista[index]),
            ),
          );
        },
```

Pero he agregado un `PopupMenuButton` el cual de momento tiene 2 opciones, ambos botones mandan a interfaces diferentes lo hice de la siguiente manera

```
trailing: PopupMenuButton<String>(
          onSelected: _choiceAction,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Constants.choices.map((String choice) {
              return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: choice,
                child: Text(choice),
              );
            }).toList();
          },
        )
```

donde **_choiceAction** es un metodo dentro de la misma clase declarado de la siguiente manera

```
void _choiceAction(String choice) {
if (choice == Constants.agregarPlay) {
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/Play_List");
} else if (choice == Constants.agregarFavorit) {
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/Registro");
}
```

}

Pero mi intención es enviar el **nombre** a la interfaz que especifique dependiendo de la selección el `PopupMenuButton`

intente agregar el siguiente metodo dentro del `PopupMenuButton` pero me da errores..  mi `Listview` completo queda de la siguiente manera

```
body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: Himnoslista.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(Himnoslista[index].tituloHimno),
        // Cuando un usuario pulsa en el ListTile, navega al DetailScreen.
        // Tenga en cuenta que no solo estamos creando un DetailScreen,
        // también le pasamos el objeto Todo actual!
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HimnoDetalle(todo: Himnoslista[index]),
            ),
          );
        },
        trailing: PopupMenuButton<String>(
          onSelected:  Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HimnoDetalle(todo: Himnoslista[index]),
            ),
          ),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Constants.choices.map((String choice) {
              return PopupMenuItem<String>(
                value: choice,
                child: Text(choice),
              );
            }).toList();
          },
        ),
      );
```

Pero me da error en las siguientes lineas que son donde se captura la selección del elemento del `PopupMenuButton`

```
onSelected:  Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HimnoDetalle(todo: Himnoslista[index]),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: que errores te da?

Comment: Cuando me coloco sobre la linea donde intento colocar el `popup` me dice lo siguiente The argument type 'Future' can´t be assigned to the parameter type '(String)->void'.

Comment: @diegoveloper edite mi pregunta para se muestre bien lo que intento y donde intento agregar el evento de selección sobre el lemento del `PopupMenuButton`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es porque el método `onSelected` espera un callBack String no un `Future` que es lo que retorna el `Navigator.push`.

Cambia esto:

```
          onSelected:  Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HimnoDetalle(todo: Himnoslista[index]),
            ),
          ),
```

Por esto:

```
          onSelected: (val) => Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HimnoDetalle(todo: Himnoslista[index]),
            ),
          ),
```